# fatal: Could not read from remote repository Gitlab

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I was committing my code and my local branch and I noticed that I was committing my code in the wrong branch then immediately I stopped the execution of commit and then created a new branch and tried to push my code, but it was throwing some errors that are new to me. My laptop is a Macbook Pro M1.

`ERROR`

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 2606:4700:90:0:f22e:fbec:5bed:a9b9 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

Something is blocking your attempt to connect to gitlab.com port 22 - it's either a firewall process on your system, or something in your local network, or something on your ISP, but wherever the block is it's effective.

As a test, try running `ssh -Tp443 git@altssh.gitlab.com`. (GitLab has attached an SSH daemon to a non-standard port on a special hostname; that port is normally used for HTTPS traffic, so it's rarely blocked.) If you're able to get a reply mentioning your GitLab username, then you can add the following to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host gitlab.com
    Hostname altssh.gitlab.com
    Port 443
```

Once you've done that, then `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` should work, and you can then clone, push, and pull to your heart's content.